Penalize absolute value while keeping the problem DPP (CVXPY)
I am trying to implement the objective function max a . x + c . abs(x - g). where all elements of c are non-positive, x  are the decision variables, and a and g are just any vector parameters.
Given I need to repeatedly solve the problem, I am trying to use a DPP formulation in CVXPY. However, this fails (I believe because both c and g are parameters, so this is taking a product of parameters). Sample code:
import cvxpy as cp
n_vars = 3
x = cp.Variable(shape=(n_vars,))
c = cp.Parameter(shape=(n_vars,), nonpos=True)
g = cp.Parameter(shape=(n_vars,))
penalization_term = c @ cp.abs(x - g)
print(f"Penalization term is: 1) DCP: {penalization_term.is_dcp()} 2) DPP: {penalization_term.is_dcp(dpp=True)}")

Output: Penalization term is: 1) DCP: True 2) DPP: False
Is there a way to reformulate the problem for it to be DPP (Disciplined Parameter Programming)?

The solution occurred to me as I was writing this... In case helpful, here it is:
import cvxpy as cp
n_vars = 3
x = cp.Variable(shape=(n_vars,))
c = cp.Parameter(shape=(n_vars,), nonpos=True)
a = cp.Parameter(shape=(n_vars,))
g = cp.Parameter(shape=(n_vars,))
g_var = cp.Variable(shape=(n_vars,))
penalization_term = c @ cp.abs(x - g_var)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(a @ x + penalization_term), [g_var == g])
print(f"Penalization term is: 1) DCP: {penalization_term.is_dcp()} 2) DPP: {penalization_term.is_dcp(dpp=True)}")
print(f"Problem is: 1) DCP: {prob.is_dcp()}, 2) DPP: {prob.is_dcp(dpp=True)}")


This is basically the same (introducing a new variable and a linear equality constraint on that) as the 1st reformulation shown at https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dpp/index.html .
